# percentage using SQL

Tags: sql

I Have an issue about percentage in SQL,I fetch a query correctly,I have this result :

```
 +----------+-------+---------+------+----+
 | nb_play  | group |         | percentage|
 +----------+-------+---------+------+----+
 | 55541    | group1          |           |
 | 02550    | group2          |           |
 | 12233    | group3          |           |
 +----------+-------+---------+------+-----
```

the result is the number of players for each group,so I have two tables players and players_group and my query is :

```
Select 
count(p.Id) as nb_play ,
pg.group
from players p 
inner join players_group pg on p.Id=pg.player_id

group by pg.group

order by pg.group;
```

so what I hope is to have percentage of number of players for each group and maybe I will have more than three groups...

Comment: Did you have any thoughts about how to do it yourself? Did you try anything? Did you thing how you can get total number of players of which the number of group players will be a percentage of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take the overall COUNT in a variable first:

```
DECLARE @totalCount AS INT
SET @totalCount = (SELECT COUNT(p.Id) from players p 
                   inner join players_group pg on p.Id=pg.player_id)

Select count(p.Id)/@totalCount * 100 as nb_play ,pg.group
 from players p 
 inner join players_group pg on p.Id=pg.player_id

 group by pg.group

 order by pg.group;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used but you may have performance problems.

```
Select 
count(p.Id) as nb_play ,
pg.group,
(count(p.Id) / (select count(1) from players) ) * 100 as percentage
from players p 
inner join players_group pg on p.Id=pg.player_id
group by pg.group
order by pg.group;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified an RDBMS, but assuming you have one that supports analytical functions you can take advantage of these (it is pretty much exactly what they are there for):

```
WITH PlayerCount AS
(   SELECT  [nb_play] = COUNT(p.ID),
            pg.[Group]
    FROM    Players p
            INNER JOIN Players_Group pg
                ON pg.Player_ID = p.ID
    GROUP BY pg.[Group]
)
SELECT  [nb_play], 
        [Group],
        [Percentage] = CAST(100.0 * [nb_Play] / SUM([nb_play]) OVER() AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
FROM    PlayerCount
```

N.b. this is written for SQL-Server but will only take small tweaks to adapt to other DBMS that support the functions

**EDIT**

This can be achieved in one single query (without CTE or subquery), but I am not sure it will be more efficient:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        [nb_play] = COUNT(p.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY pg.[Group]),
        pg.[Group],
        [Percentage] = 100.0 * COUNT(p.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY pg.[Group]) / COUNT(p.ID) OVER()
FROM    Players p
        INNER JOIN Players_Group pg
            ON pg.Player_ID = p.ID
```